# Class is never used for the CursorAdapter and can not resolve symbol for the CursorAdapter class in the Main activity

Tags: java, android

This is the code for the `CursorAdapter`

```
public class RemindersSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
public RemindersSimpleCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[]
    from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
}
```

and the class name is greyed out

in the main class

```
private ListView mListview;
private RemindersDbAdapter mDbAdapter;
private RemindersSimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;
```

the `CursorAdapter` class name is now in red.

Please help?

Comment: Just import the class .

Answer (score 0):

Do import:-

```
import com.your-package.RemindersSimpleCursorAdapter
```

Or put that in the same package by adding:-

```
package com.your-package
```